# Z Position a UIScrollView with that of SKSpriteNode

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, ios7, sprite-kit

I have a UIScrollView added onto as a subview from within the SKScene. The code is running perfectly but I am unable to fix its Z position relative to some of the SKSpriteNode existing on the main SKScene view. Is there any way this can be done. By adding the UIScrollView as a subview, its completely over the top of any other SKSpriteNodes on my scene.

Please help me out!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe what you are describing is impossible. SpriteKit is separate from UIKit, and so the zPosition means nothing to anything in UIKit.

Comment: damn..thats what i was afraid of!!

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. All elements inside a SKView are, well, part of the SKView. Any other view can only be in front of or behind the SKView.